# database reference works only by URL

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I use

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

for get access to database reference, nothing happen on button click. But when use with Firebase URL like below:

```
new Firebase("https://newonlineapp-d8272-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/
```

it works well. But the second method is not comfortable for me. I need to work in first method. Do anyone know what shall I do?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have downloaded the `google-services.json` before it included the database URL. If you download an updated file, and use *that* in your Android app, it should pick up the database URL from there.

Comment: I did a lot in that project. Now can I download it again?

Comment: Yeah, it's really just configuration data. So it doesn't really matter how much you did in the database or other services, but it *does* matter that you redownload the file after each service is first created.

Comment: Ok. Anyway I got the reason only from you. Thank you very much.