# Firebase Authentication with Google Sign-In not Writing Data to Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am encountering an issue with my Android app's Firebase authentication using Google Sign-In. The authentication process works correctly, but the user data is not being written to the Firebase Realtime Database as expected.

I have ensured that the Firebase Realtime Database rules allow both read and write operations when the user is authenticated. Here are my current rules:

```
 {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
   }
 }
```

Despite this, when a user successfully signs in with Google, the app logs the correct user information, but the data is not reflected in the Firebase Realtime Database.

Here is a snippet of the relevant code:

```
public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {    
    private SignInViewModel signInViewModel;
    private FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    private ActivitySignInBinding binding;
    private SignInClickHandler clickHandler;
    private Button googleSignInBtn;
    private GoogleSignInOptions gso;
    private GoogleSignInClient gsc;
    private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private int RC_SIGN_IN = 20;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_sign_in);
        signInViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(SignInViewModel.class);
        clickHandler = new SignInClickHandler(this, signInViewModel);
        binding.setClickHandler(clickHandler);

        googleSignInBtn = binding.googleLogInButton;
        gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().
                requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail().build();

        gsc = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        googleSignInBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                googleSignIn();
            }
        });


    }

    private void googleSignIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = gsc.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);

            try {
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuth(account.getIdToken());
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }

    private void firebaseAuth(String idToken) {
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null);
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();

                            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                            map.put("id", user.getUid());
                            map.put("name", user.getDisplayName());
                            String photoUrl = (user.getPhotoUrl() != null) ? user.getPhotoUrl().toString() : "";
                            map.put("profile", photoUrl);

                            Log.d("FirebaseGoogleAuth", "id" + user.getUid() + " " + user.getDisplayName() + " " + photoUrl);
                            database.getReference()
                                    .child("users")
                                    .child(user.getUid())
                                    .setValue(map)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            Log.d("FirebaseGoogleAuth", "Data write successful");
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FeedActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                            finish();
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            Log.d("FirebaseGoogleAuth", "error realtime database " + e.getMessage().toString());
                                        }
                                    });
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
    

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null){
            startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this, FeedActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

    }
}
```

Build Gradle (App level):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.arsoftltd.lolipop'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.arsoftltd.lolipop"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures{
        dataBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'


    // Import the Firebase BoM
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.6.0')

    // When using the BoM, don't specify versions in Firebase dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

    // Firebase Authentication
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0"

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.2'

    // Firebase realtime database
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database"


    // Facebook Sdk
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[8,9)'

    // SSP SDP library
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.1.0'



}
```

The log output during authentication shows the correct user information:

```
2023-11-27 17:17:59.062 28378-28378 FirebaseGoogleAuth com.arsoftltd.lolipop D idpuhGxZmHw7YfW49R4ZGfHJsLmus2 Md Abu Rayhan https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocIujr5T5CNmjjEps2SKElmg5ROz0Qbdl0cNcfPAUwcnvQ=s96-c
```

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on why the user data is not being written to the Firebase Realtime Database despite successful authentication. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is `onComplete` even triggered? Or are you getting any errors?

Comment: It's not getting any error and also not triggering the database onComplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since neither the `onComplete` or `onFailure` log is written, most likely your app is not connected to the database. A common way for this to happen is when your `google-services.json` file was downloaded before you created the database.

The way to fix this is to re-download `google-services.json` and replace the one in your app with an up to date version.

An alternative way to work around the problem is by specifying the URL of your database in your code when you get your `FirebaseDatabase` instance:

```
private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("your database URL here");
```

Also see:

- [Google Firebase Real-time Database Not Working as everything is set correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68173632/google-firebase-real-time-database-not-working-as-everything-is-set-correctly/68179677#68179677)
- [Firebase Realtime Database connection killed: Different Region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68806876/firebase-realtime-database-connection-killed-different-region/68807113#68807113)
- [database reference works only by URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67858941/database-reference-works-only-by-url/67860298#67860298)

Comment: I was updated the google-services.json. But I do it before creating the Realtime Database, lol. By the way thanks for remind me about it